# top command and + and * symbols

Tags: terminal, top

I am trying to fetch memory usage with below top command.

```
KiB Mem :  8009480 total,  1438848 free,  1964392 used, 4606240 buff/cache 
KiB Swap:  7340028 total,  5302364 free,  2037664 used. 5202692 avail Mem
```

```
top -p $PID -n 1 -b | grep 'KiB Mem :' | awk -F, '{print $3}'
1963780 used
```

Strangely sometimes I receive the output as

```
*"15108960+used"*
```

I am not able to understand why are the `+`,`*` symbol coming in between sometimes.

I couldn't find anything in man page about it.

What does that mean? How do I make `top` command print without `*` and `+` in the output.

Note : Running in CentOs Machine.

Comment: Why not getting the info directly from `/proc/meminfo`?

Comment: Regarding the `*` sign, could you please paste here a full line where you see it, without `grep` and `awk`? Since I've never seen it in `top`, I'm curious to see an example. You can just copy to the paste the entire Summary area of `top` where you see `*`, including the Cpu and the Swap lines.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I need it for a particular pid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `top` is not a good way to get the memory information of the machine. The `free` command is meant to be used to get memory information. You could also use `vmstat -s`.

Now, regarding `top`, I've never seen `*` character in the Summary Area, but explanation of the `+` signs appears in the man pages of [`top(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html):

```
          If you see a `+' between a displayed number and the
          following label, it means that top was forced to truncate
          some portion of that number.  By raising the scaling
          factor, such truncation can be avoided.
```

You can change the Scaling from KiB to something else using the `-E` flag or the `E` interactive command.

```
   -E  :Enforce-Summary-Memory-Scaling as:  -E  k | m | g | t | p | e
        Instructs top to force summary area memory to be scaled as:
           k - kibibytes
           m - mebibytes
           g - gibibytes
           t - tebibytes
           p - pebibytes
           e - exbibytes

        Later this can be changed with the `E' command toggle.
```

So, for instance, `-Em` will change the scaling from KiB to MiB.

But again, if you just want to get the memory information, don't use `top`, use `free`.

Comment: How can I use free command for a particular pid like the top command I used above?

Comment: @InQusitive, your `top` command didn't actually get the memory for a specific pid. I mean, it was, but then your `grep`/`awk` were only showing the **system** general memory usage, not the pid's memory usage. I'll add to my answer next week, but for now know you can use `ps` (for instace: `ps -o rss -p <pid>`) or `pidstat` (for instance: `pidstar -r -p <pid>`). Read their respective man pages for more information. You can also find memory stats in `/proc/[pid]/status`.

Comment: @InQusitive actually, it's better you open a new question on how to check process's memory usage in Linux, and show what field from `top` command you want to show, since this is a different question. Again, just remember that your current full command shows the system's general usage and not the process', so instead of using the command with `grep`/`awk`, just show the full `top` output and say which field you want to easily get for the process.

Comment: I used the /proc/[pid]/status and it's working good.